# Additional properties files for spring-batch-admin

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a web application using spring-batch and I'm now integrating spring-batch-admin for basic administration.

The problem is that the jobs configuration files (which are shared with the configuration of the existing application) use properties from files in my application's classpath, but spring-batch-admin's context is not able to load them.

The quick solution was to override the `placeholderProperties` [bean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/env-context.xml) in spring-batch-admin just to add my properties files:

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/bootstrap/batch.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:batch-default.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:hsql}.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:/path/to/jobs-config.properties</value> <!-- adding my properties here -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

I don't want to move my properties to one of spring-batch-admin's default files. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here...

As described in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/jobs.html#Add_your_Own_Job_Executions), every job configuration file placed under `META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/*.xml` is loaded by spring-batch-admin as a child context and property placeholders from the parent (i.e. [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/env-context.xml) default bean) are inherited, but the child context can always create its own placeholder bean.

Given that, in my case, the job configuration files are shared with an existing application and use properties from the application classpath, the solution is to create a new job file in `META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/*.xml` specific for spring-batch-admin:

```
<!-- placeholder bean with additional properties for the child context -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/path/to/job-config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<!-- external job configuration file is imported -->
<import resource="classpath*:/path/to/job.xml" />
```

Comment: documentation link is dead