# Load additional property file in spring batch admin

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

[image]

I am facing a issue in reading an additional property file

> src/main/resources/default.properties

from

> META-INF/batch/jobs-infra.xml.

I have followed the instructions given in  - [load external config file in spring batch admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465345/load-external-config-file-in-spring-batch-admin/30779062#30779062). But not sure the location where I placed the files.

Please, check my application folder structure attached for your reference. I need a help on this.

Comment: How did you configure that properties file being brought in?

Comment: I placed a file META-INF/spring/batch/override/manager/env-context.xml. In that, I have added the same content given in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465345/load-external-config-file-in-spring-batch-admin/30779062#30779062" but for the property location I have given the value="classpath:batch-default.properties".

Comment: Can you share that configuration?